# find and replace complex regex line using sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am using environment variables and want to simply find a line containing environment variable and replace it with the entire line that consists of special characters.

Details:
`file="dir1/file1"`

In short, I am trying to find a line in a file that contains `$file` and as soon as it finds it, replace entire line with the below line:

```
('test/$file', [your.name, your.age, your.address]),
```

(please note the comma in end)

Command that I tried:

```
sed -i '/'$file'.*/c ('"'test/$file'"'," [hello.name, hello.age, hello.address]),' file_name
```

sed: 1: "file": invalid command code f

Please note that I want to replace the entire line. The problem lies with the complex string that I am replacing which consists of brackets, commas, slashes. It is not getting replaced.

Comment: It's not clear if you want `$project_path` expanded on the search or replace or both. Please show sample input and expected output.

Comment: Again, please [edit] your question to include sample input and expected output that shows that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to use sed for that as it doesn't understand literal strings (see [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)), use awk instead:

```
awk -v old="$project_path" \
    -v new="app('projects/$project_path', [hello.dev, hello.stage, hello.prod])," \
    'index($0,old){$0=new} 1' file
```

The above assumes `$project_path` doesn't contain escapes, if it can see [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for alternatives to `-v`, and that you want `$project_path` expanded in both the search and replacement strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```bash
sed -r "s:^.*[\$]file.*\$:('test/\$file', [your.name, your.age, your.address]),:g" file_name
```

Here:

- `:` - delimiter of sed
- `^.*[\$]file.*\$` - regex searching for your line

  - `^.*` - everything from the beginning of line
  - `[\$]` - dollar sign in ERE regex
  - `file` - name of your "variable"
  - `.*\$` - everything until the end of line

Also, notice all `$` escaped with `\`, because replacement command enclosed in double quotes. I think escaping `$` more pleasant for eye, than escaping single quotes.